# passing allocator object to STL container

Tags: c++, stl

I am thinking of how to pass allocator object to STL C++ containers, for example as below

```
std::allocator<int> intAlloc;
vector<int, intAlloc> v1;
```

I do aware of we can do like below

```
vector<int, std::allocator<int> > v2;
```

I am think of options of how to pass a same allocator object to all vector objects instead of passing allocator type.

Comment: Do you want `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > v2(intAlloc);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by Jarod above. I am looking for some thing below which can be achieved by using same allocator object for both vectors.

```
std::allocator<int> intAlloc;
vector<int, std::allocator<int> > v2(intAlloc);
vector<int, std::allocator<int> > v2(intAlloc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The allocator [*is* shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) between all objects of this type:

> Every standard library component that may need to allocate or release
>   storage, from std::string, std::vector, and every container except
>   std::array, to std::shared_ptr and std::function, does so through an
>   Allocator: an object of a class

It is, in other words, impossible to *not* share the allocator between objects.